# My Dijkstra code in java is not working for most of the inputs...what is wrong with this code?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-KJ4TN8DpT9Zk1LTWpxRGZqZEk/view?usp=sharing

This is the link to my code. Please review it and share your thought in this (I am a beginner in Algorithms)

Actually, the code first wants for the number of test cases and then the size of the test case and number of edges in one line, then there are lines containing edges, last line of one test case is the source..here is a input example:

2

4 2

1 2

1 3

1

3 1

2 3

2

That means to test cases, for the 1st test case: 4 nodes and 2 edges, 1 is the source for 1st case...
Below is my code snippet:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc;
        int test = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        for(int i =0; i < test; i++)
        {
            String temp = scan.nextLine();
            sc = new Scanner(temp);
            int size = sc.nextInt();
            int edge = sc.nextInt();
            int bfs[][] = new int[size+1][size+1];

            for(int j = 0; j < edge; j++)
            {
                temp = scan.nextLine();
                sc = new Scanner(temp);
                int row = sc.nextInt();
                int clm = sc.nextInt();
                bfs[row][clm] = 1;
                bfs[clm][row] = 1;
            }

            int src = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            int visit[] = search(src, bfs);

            for(int j = 1; j < visit.length; j++)
            {
                if(visit[j] == 1)
                {
                    System.out.print("6"+" ");
                }

                else if(j != src)
                {
                    System.out.print("-1 ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int[] search(int src, int[][]bfs)
    {
        int [] visit = new int[bfs.length];
        int[] color = new int[bfs.length];
        color[src] = 1;

        Queue q = new LinkedList();
        q.add(src);

        while(q.size() != 0)
        {
            int temp = (int) q.remove();

            for(int i = 1; i < bfs[temp].length; i++)
            {
                if(bfs[temp][i] == 1 && color[i] == 0)
                {
                    visit[i] = 1;
                    color[i] = 1;
                    q.add(i);
                }
            }
        }

        return visit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code snippet here over link

Comment: I am trying to passte the code in the question description....but it is showing indentation error, i'm new here, so can't do it perfectly

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ishan. Please consider having a look at [ask].

Comment: I have added you code, please review

Comment: also provide bad input/ouput cases  and expected output to make question more clear

Comment: Thanks Fildor and Prasun.yap i'm making it more clear

Comment: Now its edited...hope y'll will understand